# Access base class member from a method in a class inside derived class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is the situation:

```
class Base
{
 object* mainObject;
}

class Derived :
 public Base
{
 class aTrain
 {
   void* something;
   .
   .
   .
   ~aTrain()
   {
    mainObject->destroyingMethod(something);
   }
 };
}
```

Outputs: **a nonstatic member reference must be relative to specific object.**

I can understand the problem, yet how can I solve this without passing the Derived class to aTrain constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve this without passing some sort of reference to `mainobject` in to `aTrain`. Whether you do this by passing a reference to a `Derived` object in to the `aTrain` constructor or by passing a reference to `mainobject` in to `aTrain` via a member function of `aTrain` or any other possible combination is up to you.

The thing is that there is *no* implicit way for an inner class to access non-static members of the class that it is contained in.

Answer (score 2):

Defining `aTrain` inside `Derived` affects the scope and access of the **type** `aTrain`.

It does not mean that every `aTrain` has an associated `Derived`.  There can be any number of `aTrain` instances and separately any number of `Derived` instances.

So if you want every `aTrain` to know about some `Derived` instance, you will have to implement that, with a pointer or reference member.